# can not read some string from struts.properties

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struts

I have define variable error in struts.properties as follows:

```
error=this is an error
```

Now I can call this error as follows:

```
ErrorMsg = "<s:property value='getText(\"error\")'/>";
```

and it works, the result is: ErrorMsg=this is an error

How to get the text of variable instead of string?
I tried the following:

```
var m="error";
  error1 = "<s:property value='getText(m)'/>";
  error2 = "<s:property value='getText(\"m\")'/>";
```

I use firebug debugger and error1 and error2 are displyed as follows:

```
error1=""
error2=""
```

Any Idea?
thank you in advance

Comment: Either I'm not understanding something or the title of the question is wrong.

Comment: error1 should be "this is an error", but it is empty, the question is WHY :)

Comment: you cannot pass m="error" to struts property tag. You should define the value m in your action then you can access here. or else hard code the value in getText('error').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing server side and client side code.

The s:property tags will be evaluated first on the server side, long before any value of m is valid, as that is client side JavaScript code.

If you post what you're trying to achieve then I or someone else may be able to help further.

HTH